# PHP dynamically parse nested multidimensional JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, json, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have multiple JSON files on my server that I need to parse and then insert the parsed data into my database.  For each file, I need to parse the nested “datasets” sets array, which also contains multiple nested arrays, and then insert the data from the multiple nested arrays into my database.

Each file contains differing and ever-changing nested datasets, so I am attempting to write a script that will dynamically build a sql insert statement using data from the arrays.

**EXAMPLE JSON DATA**

```
 {
"title" : "Exported Data",
"timestamp":"3/17/2017 10:35:13 PM",   //  I need the date from this string timestamp
"description":"this is unused",
"datasets":[
    {
        "ab":[{               //  I need this key value “ab” for the table name
                "STID":"1",   //  I need both the “STID” for the column name, and the value for the record row
                "qty":"440",
                "bal":"532882.71",
                "rem":"11.52"
            },
            {
                "STID":"2",
                "qty":"393",
                "bal":"406825.45",
                "rem":"11.16"
            },
            {
                "STID":"3",
                "qty":"517",
                "bal":"556259.82",
                "rem":"11.13"
            }]
    },

    {
        "act":[{
                "STID":"1",
                "BEG":"586",
                "DEL":"2",
                "RET":"3",
                "EBO":"1",
                "PO":"0",
                "CO":"0",
                "TX":"2",
                "RX":"3",
                "CUR":"584",
                "PTD":"-2",
                "WTD":"-19",
                "MTD":"-6"
            },
            {
                "STID":"2",
                "BEG":"519",
                "DEL":"12",
                "RET":"2",
                "EBO":"1",
                "PO":"0",
                "CO":"0",
                "TX":"0",
                "RX":"0",
                "CUR":"528",
                "PTD":"9",
                "WTD":"-3",
                "MTD":"65"
            },
            {
                "STID":"3",
                "BEG":"682",
                "DEL":"6",
                "RET":"4",
                "EBO":"2",
                "PO":"0",
                "CO":"0",
                "TX":"0",
                "RX":"0",
                "CUR":"682",
                "PTD":"0",
                "WTD":"2",
                "MTD":"22"
            }]
    },

   {
        "cashproj":[{
                "STID":"1",
                "DlyProj":"2542.4025",
                "RentCol":"1090.33",
                "PerCol":"42.8858"
            },
            {
                "STID":"2",
                "DlyProj":"1893.44",
                "RentCol":"2214.48",
                "PerCol":"116.9553"
            },
            {
                "STID":"3",
                "DlyProj":"2614.24",
                "RentCol":"1508.06",
                "PerCol":"57.6863"
            }]
    }
]}
```

-

The MySQL tables are named the same as the dataset’s nested array key (i.e. “ab”, “act”, “cashproj”, etc…).

For each dataset, I am wanting to loop through each nested array to then create and run a sql query using data from both the top-level array key values, the dataset key name, and then the dataset array keys and values, for example:

**This is what I currently have:**

```
$the_array = json_decode($json, true);
$topdata = new RecursiveArrayIterator($the_array);

$start = 'INSERT INTO ';

foreach ($topdata as $key => $value)
{
    if($key == 'timestamp')
    {
        $timestamp = strtotime($value);
    }
    if($key == 'datasets')
    {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v)
        {
            foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2)
            {
                foreach ($v2 as $dataset => $dsvalue)
                {
                    $col = '';
                    $val = '';
                    foreach ($dsvalue as $dskey => $dsval)
                    {
                        $col .= $dskey . ', ';
                        $val .= $dsval . ', ';
                        // echo "$dskey => $dsval <br>";
                    }
                    $col = rtrim($col,", ");
                    $val = rtrim($val,", ");
                    $sql = $start . $k2 . ' (date, ' . $col . ') VALUES (' . $timestamp . ', ' . $val . ')';
                    // echo $sql . '<br><br>';
                    // $q = new Query();
                    // $q->insertDB($sql);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm hoping someone can show me a better or more-efficient method of writing this, that doesn't include five nested foreach statements.

Additionally, I'm not sure I am handling the conversion of the timestamp correctly.  I will later use this column in conjunction with DateDiff/DateAdd to find data between periods. If current method is not right, what is?

Thanks in advance for your time and response.

Comment: [This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) should help you, at least a little bit

Comment: Thank you GMC.  That did help a bit.